# Infopath form missing upload file on ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have customized a from in InfoPath and now i've lost the upload file ability in the rich text box.

[image]

I've added an attachment section to my form which will allow me to upload a file but i then run into the issue that when i run start task workflow the file is not transferred to the task.

If there is no solution to the missing upload file button on the ribbon, is there a way to add the attachment to the task workflow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The rich text control in InfoPath form does not have the Upload File feature.

To work it around, you can insert a link instead. Click on INSERT tab from the Ribbon and then click on the Link button. It will give two options: From the SharePoint and From an Address. Browser your files.

Another workaround, use Attachments control as you mentioned. To retrieve all of the files that are attached to a list item in the workflow, we need to call REST API:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(current item id)/AttachmentFiles/
```

Working with files attached to list items by using REST:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#FileAttachments

How to call REST API to get attachments in the SharePoint Designer workflow:

https://sshareasolutions.com/2017/09/20/sharepoint-list-attachment-url-in-email-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-and-rest-api/